# How to return Max number in Excel from 2 columns

Tags: excel, maxifs

I'm creating an excel spreadsheet to record results in a darts league. By entering the singles and pairs results from each match played including the number of tons scored, 180s hit, highest outshot and fastest leg, it automatically populates team score, league tables and lists of most legs won, most tons, most 180s etc.

I have everything working apart from Max formula for highest outshot.

As players can be both home and away during a season, I have four columns, `Home Player`, `Home Outshot` and `Away Player`, `Away Outshot`.

**Screenshot of singles table**

[image: Screenshot of singles table]

I want to find a formula that will look at the `Home Player` name and `Home Outshot`, then compare that to `Away Player` name and `Away Outshot` and then only report back with the highest outshot from both columns against that players name.

Basically its looking for every instance of Player 1, whether they were home or away and then pulling back the highest outshot they scored during the league season.

Is that even possible?

I have a list of players in a table (PlayersTable) and a column for each players [Highest Out].

**Players Table**

[image: Players Table]

I have used a formula to pull in the highest outshot from a singles match results (Singles) which lists all the stats from each game played. It works if I separate home and away as below:

```
{=MAX(IF(Singles[Home Player]=B4,Singles[Home Outshot]))} 
{=MAX(IF(Singles[Away Player]=B4,Singles[Away Outshot]))}
```

but I can't combine the two, it's one or the other.

On a separate worksheet I've created a list of the highest outshot overall I'm using:

```
=LARGE((ROUND(PlayerTable[Highest Out],2)+ROW(PlayerTable[Highest Out])/10000),A41)
```

To pull in the Players name I enter the following formula:

```
=INDEX(PlayerTable[Player],MATCH(C41,(ROUND(PlayerTable[Highest Out],2)+ROW(PlayerTable[Highest Out])/10000),0))
```

That works fine but because the PlayerTable only contains home or away, not both, the second list only contains home or away.

**Overall table for Highest Outshot**

[image: Overall table for Highest Outshot]

It would be great if I could combine home and away players and outshots into an array formula so it looks at both columns and pulls in the highest outshot for each player in the league.

Comment: just take the max of the two: `=MAX(MAX(IF(Singles[Home Player]=B4,Singles[Home Outshot])),MAX(IF(Singles[Away Player]=B4,Singles[Away Outshot])))`

Comment: Might be easier to use `MaxIfS` if your version of Excel supports it

Comment: Hi Scott Craner, that is perfect, did exactly what I needed, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Chris Neilsen, I have Office 365 which supports MAXIFS but it doesn't let you pick two columns to pull information from. It allows you to use criteria from a few columns but only bring back results from 1 column.

Comment: Hi Scott Craner, how would you do the same with this formula:

Comment: =MIN(IF((Singles[Home Player]=B3)*(Singles[Home Fastest Leg]>0),Singles[Home Fastest Leg]))
Basically I'm looking for the lowest darts used to win a leg but ignoring 0. Again it works for home players or away players but not together. I tried using your logic from the formula you provided but it didn't like it.